# Localizing Winforms using the form designer with state changes

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio, localization

I am having an issue where when using the `localizable` property in the windows forms designer. I have a label that has its `Text` property set by a resource file, and I want that text to change to another string in the resource file when a button is clicked. There is no issue adding the new string to the resource files or getting the strings with a resource manager. The problem is that every time I open the form designer, the resource generator wipes out that new string that was manually added.

**Q: Is there a way,using best practices, to have generated localization resources from the designer and manually created ones live happily together?**

I was under the impression that the Microsoft documentation states not to mix project and form resource files for localization, which is why I'm not taking that approach. Though I may have misunderstood the rational as indicated in [this document](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y99d1cd3(v=vs.90).aspx).

**EDIT: Reproducible steps**

**1.** Create a windows form (Form1) with a button (button1) and a label (label1)

**2.** set `label1.Text = "Hello";`

**3.** set the `localizable` property of Form1 in the designer to *true*

**4.** In the Form1.resx file that is generated, add a string resource named "strWorld" with a value of "world". When you start typing, click okay on the message box that appears; agreeing that you are foolish enough to modify the resource file that is part of the form.

***Steps 5 and 6 optional***

**5.** Add the following eventHandler

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ResourceManager resources = new ComponentResourceManager(typeof(Form1));
   label1.Text = resources.GetString("strWorld");
}
```

**6.** Build and start the application to verify that the button functions

**7.** return to the designer and nudge the button by a pixel or two (or change anything else)

**8.** return to Form1.resx to find strWorld gone.

I am trying to figure out how one can visually align elements in different languages, taking advantage of the form designer, have controls that change properties of elements from said resource files and stay within recommended practices. Does one have to roll their own code around this or use a 3rd party solution or is there just something that I'm missing? Surely this is a common enough issue.

Comment: Your previous question gave a hint that you did something unwise with the form's .resx file.  Not mentioning any of this and providing *less* info makes it very hard to help you.

Comment: Hans, ignore my previous question. They are two different questions. That one was all manual, this is asking about using the designer and having state changes. Please ask clarifying questions if the information you need isn't in my initial question. If I knew what you needed to know to provide an answer, I would have included it. Broad statements of insuficient information don't help anyone.

Comment: It is the same underlying problem.  You must provide repro steps to get a useful answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Microsoft expect you to do define texts

- in the designer or
- in the source code

If you enable localization, texts you specify in the designer will be stored in the local resx files associated with the form or the user control.

For each property in the designer, you can specify one text only.

If you want to change the text at runtime, you should define the text in the source code, and update it from your code.

Microsoft would expect you localize this text using named resources, which would be defined in the Resources.resx file at project level. The localized versions would be in localized versions of Resources.resx.

(If you define additional resources of your own in the "local" resource file associated with a form, the designer will probably discard them.)

I don't know if that is "best practice", but I think that is how Microsoft expect you to work.